# SipDemo sample code gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, sip

i'm developping SIP application. I used SipDemo sample from [SipDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html) but something is wrong. I've got NullPointerException => "Error when trying to close manager." in this place (exception 'e'):

```
public void initiateCall() {

    updateStatus(sipAddress);

    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                call.toggleMute();
                updateStatus(call);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                updateStatus("Ready.");
            }
        };

        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 30);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall", "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
        if (me != null) {
            try {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                        "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Additionaly i checked this `SipManager.isApiSupported()` and  `SipManager.isVoipSupported()` and both returned **false**. I'm testing this on Tab with 4.0.3 OS. I wondered if the fault is in not support native sip, but i can easy make a call with SipDroid or another app from market.

**EDIT**
Logcat stack trace:

```
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247): Error when trying to close manager.
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at com.example.android.sip.WalkieTalkieActivity.initiateCall(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:212)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at com.example.android.sip.WalkieTalkieActivity$4.onClick(WalkieTalkieActivity.java:324)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:165)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-15 22:29:11.255: INFO/WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall(4247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: print the stack trace of the exception and post it, or simply add verification that each object is non-null before you try to call any of it's methods.

Comment: Either `manager` or `me` is null.

Comment: yeah i know, `me` is null, but why? I think it's because `SipManager.isApiSupported()` and `SipManager.isVoipSupported()` return false but it mean that SIP **is not supported**

Comment: That, rather than null pointer exception, should be the subject of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got some solution. Not every version of android supports sip. Therefore, you should look for 3rd part library. For example you can see the source code of [Sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/) or [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) and convert for your own needs.

Comment: I am struggling from long time do u have working sample of it

Comment: Yes I was able to successfully build an application based on these projects, however, these projects are very large and most of their functions was to me unnecessary and minimizing them was difficult. So i found another solution, I found a PJSIP library in which these projects are based and I heve implemented it on my own.